# Insert interval labels on plot

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I have a plot with 7 intervals:

```
t=0:0.001:10;
y_fcn = @(t) 0.2*cos(t) + cos(1.4*t) + 0.8*cos(5.2*t) + 0.02*randn(1, length(t));
plot(t, y_fcn(t), '-b');
hold on
I = [1, 1430, 2859, 4288, 5717, 7146, 8575, 10001];
plot(t(I), y_fcn(t(I)), '*r')
```

I want on plot 7 labels that indicates the intervals as (w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7).
Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the labels to appear? On the graph? On an axis?

Comment: I posted also on matlab website, you can see the plot http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/114150-how-create-lines-on-plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`text`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text.html) and [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) (double arrow) to indicate your intervals. Note however that for some reason, `annotation` uses normalized figure units to specify the `x` and `y` coordinates of your annotations, so you may want to use this very useful utility function from the File Exchange to convert your coordinates from data space to normalized figure units: [Data space to figure units conversion](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion).

**EDIT:**
As I'm feeling generous, it would probably look like that:

```
t=0:0.001:10;
y_fcn = @(t) 0.2*cos(t) + cos(1.4*t) + 0.8*cos(5.2*t) + 0.02*randn(1, length(t));
plot(t, y_fcn(t), '-b');
axis([min(t) max(t) -2 3]);
hold on
I = [1, 1430, 2859, 4288, 5717, 7146, 8575, 10001];
plot(t(I), y_fcn(t(I)), '*r')

for k=1:length(I)-1
    [xa,ya] = ds2nfu([t(I(k)) t(I(k+1))],[2.5 2.5]);
    annotation('doublearrow',xa,ya,'Color','r')
    y_lim = get(gca,'ylim');
    line([t(I(k)) t(I(k))],y_lim,'Color','r','LineStyle',':')
    text(0.5*(t(I(k))+t(I(k+1))),2.7,['w' num2str(k)],'Color','r')
end
```

Comment: Sorry, is not running,  Error in Untitled (line 10)
 [xa,ya] = ds2nfu([t(I(k)), t(I(k+1))],[2.5 2.5]);

Comment: Have you downloaded the utility function "Data space to figure units conversion" as I suggested in my answer? That's what this is. You need to download it and place it on your MATLAB path.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
strings = {'w1';'w2';'w3';'w4';'w5';'w6';'w7'};
x_strings = (t(I(1:7))+t(I(2:8)))/2; %// center of each interval
y_strings = y_fcn(x_strings) + .9; %// height from y_fcn. Adjust ".9" as needed
text(x_strings,y_strings,strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to see the different lines on the legend, I would recommend plotting them separately. Here is a small scale example:

```
plot(1:100,1:100,101:200,101:200)
legend('a','b')
```

Comment: I am not looking for legend, I want insert the labels that indicates the interval close to the plot.

Comment: @user3209872 Could you perhaps create an example (using paint or so) and add it to the question?

Comment: Sorry Dennis, I don’t have enough point to put a figure on Stackoverflow.  I have my interval points (I), I want label interval (for example from 1:1430) on plot. I tried to use text insert or clabel. It is not working. Run my file and you can see the intervals.
Thanks